# Looking for ArcGIS API for javascript and Jquery samples

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, jquery

I'm new in ArcGIS javascript API .I found tons of samples of ArcGIS javascript API  and DOJO . it was very interesting for me but i know Jquery and i'd like to use Jquery to develop webgis.Is there any resources and samples about using ArcGIS javascript API and Jquery ? 
Thanks for advance.

Comment: Are you looking for something other than the [top Google hit](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/framework_jquery.html) for "jquery arcgis"?

Comment: @blah238 yes . I'm looking for more samples.The website just Illustrate one sample

Comment: @wetland +1 vote for this on ArcGIS Idea http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bsrj&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a300000004xET%26category%3DWeb%2BApps%2Band%2BAPIs

Comment: Unfortunately, Esri decided the base their API on Dojo. I'm just saying that because its important to understand that the API code actually uses Dojo pretty extensively - its not just that they happened to use it for the examples. 

So you will have to learn some Dojo anyway, unless you want to recreate in jQuery the tools they have developed already based on Dojo. I'm with you though. I'd prefer to use jQuery.

Comment: If you load the compact version of ESRI's JavaScript API, you can load jQuery beside it with (hopefully) no conflict. You'll still need to use Dojo to handle things within the map, but you can use jQuery for everything outside the map with no problems.